# BI Publisher Excel template Preview Error

Tags: java, xml, excel, xml-parsing, bi-publisher

Can anyone please guide me about the problem and how to resolve it.I am unable to understand the error which is mentioned below:-

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at oracle.xdo.template.excel.render.BookDataWriter.copyCell(BookDataWriter.java:766)
at oracle.xdo.template.excel.render.BookDataWriter.finishCell(BookDataWriter.java:699)
at oracle.xdo.template.excel.render.CellHandler.endElement(CellHandler.java:111)
at oracle.xdo.template.excel.render.BookDataParser.endElement(BookDataParser.java:203)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLContentHandler.endElement(XMLContentHandler.java:211)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1554)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:409)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:355)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:319)
at oracle.xdo.template.excel.render.BookDataParser.parserXMLDocument(BookDataParser.java:137)
at oracle.xdo.template.excel.ExcelController.processActionLanguage(ExcelController.java:366)
at oracle.xdo.template.excel.ExcelController.process(ExcelController.java:240)
at oracle.xdo.template.ExcelProcessor.process(ExcelProcessor.java:244)
at ExcelPreview.runXDO(ExcelPreview.java:110)
at ExcelPreview.main(ExcelPreview.java:87)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to parse the text as numberic value like float. But that text is having multiple dot "." in it. Seems you are reading an excel which have this kind of dirty data.